# What am I doing wrong on this conditional?

Tags: price, special-price

I've put together a blurb to show logged out customers what they can pay if they create an account and log in.

Some of our products don't have a lower price so I want to omit the blurb for products that don't have a lower price when logged in. I tried a conditional to look for conditions where the product prices were different between the two states.

```
<!-- Add price discount code here -->
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
<?php $_productA = $this->getProduct();
$_productB = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productA->getId());  
$_productB->setCustomerGroupId(4);
if ($_productB != $_productA ) {
echo '<p>If you were logged in,<br />your price would be: $'.round($_productB->getFinalPrice(),2).'<br/>';
} ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- End price discount code here -->
```

But it shows the code on every product. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just checking if the two product objects are the same. In order to know about the price you would need to call `$product->getPrice()`

```
if ($_productB->getPrice() != $_productA->getPrice() ) {
    echo '<p>If you were logged in,<br />your price would be:  $'.round($_productB->getFinalPrice(),2).'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Outstanding. And, in addition, I needed to compare: 

`code` $_productB->getFinalPrice() != $_productA->getPrice()

Thanks a million.